# Как сделать ленту фотографий на android

Tags: java, android

Нужно чтобы у каждого, кто откроет приложение была кнопка добавить фотографию и каждый смог загрузить, фотография добавляется в общую ленту(как в инстраграмме).

Как это реализовать и с чего начать?

Comment: *У меня есть компьютер, как сделать на нем GTA5*. Начать с разбиения задачи на части. Дальше решать отдельно каждую задачу. Дальше слепить все воедино.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Создайте кнопку.
2. Повесьте на неё слушатель нажатий.
3. По нажатию получайте как-то фотку (через камеру, галерею, проводник etc)
4. После получения фотки отсылайте её на сервер.
5. В ленте делайте запрос к серверу на получение адресов фоток.
6. Получив адреса - отобразите их в списке

Comment: Как отправить фотку на сервер?

Comment: @MartinezToni обычно это делают POST-запросом, передавай файл в виде значения к-л параметра.

Comment: И как картинка запишется в бд?

Comment: В БД пишите путь к картинке. Файл в БД хоанить не надо